# Put button on the right side of the div

Tags: css

I have a div and a button and i want to put them beside each other.Problem is that, doesnt matter what i do, my button ends up on the next line.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xhEG6/

```
<div id="askQuestionOverDiv" "><h1>Text</h1></div>     

<input type="button" id="Text" style="float:right;" value="Text" />

#askQuestionOverDiv {

     height:40px; 

width: 70%;   
     text-align:center;
     border-radius:15px;
      background: #141414;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);

}

  #askQuestionOverDiv h1 {

        color:white;

    }


        #askQuestionOverDiv h1:hover {

       text-decoration:underline;
       cursor:pointer;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you html **up** to **down** as like this

```
<input type="button" id="Text" style="float:right;" value="Text" />

<div id="askQuestionOverDiv" "><h1>Text</h1></div>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhEG6/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***display:inline-block***. And can also try ***float*** attribute.